# Servicestack IRequestLogger get the IHttpRequest

Tags: servicestack

I am implementing the Logging of the request and response in ServiceStack. I wanted to get hold of IHttpRequest in my IRequestLogger.Log() method.

The IRequestContext does not have info like the IHttpRequest, Is there a way I can get that passed or accessed.  I am trying to log the Request Headers, UserAgent, token etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [IRequestLogger.Log](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Web/IRequestLogger.cs#L54) is injected with the current `IRequest`.

You can cast to `IHttpRequest` for HTTP Requests as well as get access to the underlying ASP.NET or HttpListener request by casting `IRequest.OriginalRequest`, e.g:

```
void Log(IRequest request, object requestDto, object response, TimeSpan elapsed)
{
    var httpReq = request as IHttpRequest;
    var aspReq = request.OriginalRequest as HttpRequestBase;     
}
```

Comment: Ah Thanks.This is what I needed .